# Erlang NIF Test -- OS X Lion

Tags: c, gcc, erlang, erlang-nif

I'm trying to compile the NIF Test from Erlang (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html) on Mac OS X Lion. I can't get it to compile. Am I missing a compiler flag? Here's the error I get:

```
Computer:~ me $ gcc -fPIC -shared -o niftest.so niftest.c -I /usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R14B02/lib/erlang/usr/include/
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_enif_make_string", referenced from:
      _hello in ccXfh0oG.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've also tried this with `-m32` but it says there's no i386 architecture either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

for 64-bit Erlang, the following works for me:

```
gcc -undefined dynamic_lookup -dynamiclib niftest.c -o niftest.so \
    -I /usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R14B02/lib/erlang/usr/include
```

Comment: Dynamic lookup it is! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your problem is not architecture but undefined symbol `_enif_make_string`, which means that you have to link with your `enif` library, whatever it is, using `-l` option. Also, it's been a long time since I built a shared library for OS X, but I think that the right flag to use is `-dynamiclib` and not `-shared`, and you don't have to have a space after `-I`.

Comment: If I have the `#include` directive and the -I flag, shouldn't that be enough to reference the include file? Check out the link. Thanks!

Comment: @TravisPowell: No, `#include` is enough only for compiling but not for linking. Your bug is in linking, see `ld: sym...`. It is linker bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try using these flags when compiling your nif instead of -shared

```
-bundle -flat_namespace -undefined suppress
```