# Elixir NIF- Hello World example on x64 Mac OSX

Tags: macos, erlang, native, elixir, erlang-nif

Hi I'm trying to get the *Hello World* example for Erlang NIF (*Native Implemented Function*) shown here
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html
to work from Elixir on OSX 64bit.

First I create the C-code:

```
/* niftest.c */
#include "erl_nif.h"

static ERL_NIF_TERM hello(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[])
{
    return enif_make_string(env, "Hello world!", ERL_NIF_LATIN1);
}

static ErlNifFunc nif_funcs[] =
{
    {"hello", 0, hello}
};

ERL_NIF_INIT(niftest,nif_funcs,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

Then I successfully compile it using `gcc` for 64 bit architecture as suggested here
[Erlang NIF Test -- OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288358/erlang-nif-test-os-x-lion#answer-8288951)

```
gcc -undefined dynamic_lookup -dynamiclib niftest.c -o niftest.so -I /usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R14B02/lib/erlang/usr/include
```

which produces the necessary file `niftest.so` that I should be able to interface-into from Erlang/Elixir.  My Elixir (niftest.ex) looks like this (inspired by a more complex example reported [here](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/16/elixir-native-interoperability-ports-vs-nifs/)):

```
defmodule Niftest do
 @onload :init
  def init() do
    :erlang.load_nif("./niftest", 0)
    :ok
  end

  def hello() do
    "NIF library not loaded"
  end

end
```

Now with niftest.so and niftest.ex in the same directory I fire up elixir using `iex` and type in `Niftest.hello` and all I get back is: **"NIF library not loaded"**

Am I missing a vital step? - please help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The load of the library is failing silently. You can assert that it succeeds using:

```
:ok = :erlang.load_nif("./niftest", 0)
```

This results in an error:

```
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value:
{:error, {:bad_lib, 'Library module name \'niftest\' does not match calling module \'\'Elixir.Niftest\'\''}}
niftest.ex:4: Niftest.init/0
```

That happens because a NIF lib can only be called from its "owning" module. The name of that module is the first argument to the `ERL_NIF_INIT` macro, so you can fix this by changing that call and recompiling:

```
ERL_NIF_INIT(Elixir.Niftest,nif_funcs,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

There is also a typo in the load hook. It should be:

```
@on_load :init
```

Comment: You are right - yours will be the accepted answer - many thanks!

Comment: It turns out that the @onload :init directive doesn't works as expected either - so I have to manually call Niftest.init before I call Nifteast.hello. Not sure why.

Comment: `@onload` doesn't work because it should be `@on_load`. Updated the answer

Comment: doh! too much javascript on the brain - thanks for spotting that!